# AWS BATCH - SubmitJob operation: Job Queue is attached to Compute Environment that can not run Jobs with capability EC2

Tags: boto3, serverless-framework, aws-fargate, aws-batch

I am trying to deploy an AWS Batch with Fargate type but when I try to submit a job to this batch I got the following error

An error occurred (ClientException) when calling the SubmitJob operation: Job Queue is attached to Compute Environment that can not run Jobs with capability EC2

---

This is the configuration that I'm using to create my resources with serverless-framework

```yaml
resources:
  Resources:
    SlsComputeEnv:
        Type: AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment
        Properties:
          Type: MANAGED
          ServiceRole: !GetAtt BatchServiceRole.Arn
          ComputeEnvironmentName: ${self:custom.batch.compute_env}
          ComputeResources:
            MaxvCpus: 32
            SecurityGroupIds: 
              - security
            Subnets:
              - subnet
            Type: FARGATE
          State: ENABLED
      SlsJobQueue:
        Type: AWS::Batch::JobQueue
        Properties:
          JobQueueName: ${self:custom.batch.job_queue}
          ComputeEnvironmentOrder:
            - Order: 1
              ComputeEnvironment: !Ref SlsComputeEnv
          State: ENABLED
          Priority: 1
      SlsJobDefinition:
        Type: AWS::Batch::JobDefinition
        Properties:
          Type: container
          JobDefinitionName: ${self:custom.batch.job_definition}
          ContainerProperties:
            ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt FargateExecutionRole.Arn
            ResourceRequirements:
              - Type: MEMORY
                Value: 8
              - Type: VCPU
                Value: 4
            Image: ecr-path
```

python code to submit a job

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client("batch")
client.submit_job(
        jobName=f"test-fargate-dev",
        jobQueue=BATCH_JOB_QUEUE_ARN,
        jobDefinition=BATCH_JOB_DEFINITION,
        containerOverrides={
            "command": ["python3", "script.py"],
            "environment": [
                {"name": "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION", "value": "us-east-1"},
                {"name": "stage", "value": "dev"},
            ],
        },
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify that your job is a Fargate job in platformCapabilities (with a Fargate version - i'd recommend 1.4). See Job Definitions section in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/fargate.html

Answer (score 1):

The launch might not be reflected already in the CFN Resource Spec. They should be soon(-ish). Here are the notes of someone who already did use Fargate on batch via CFN: https://github.com/pplu/cfn-fargate-batch